# Starting Node.JS using a simple web hosting plan

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

This might be a very nooby question and I myself do not believe there is any way, but I just want to give it a try.
So: I rented just a web hosting, where I built websites using php. But since it is just a web hosting plan, I have no access to a terminal. I want to publish a website which I previously developed and ran on my own computer. I do not want to rent a whole server, because it needs to be secured and this is out of my current knowledge, so is there any way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: define what you mean by "website". Is there any serverside code running in nodejs? Or just serving of static content? If you have nodejs backend code, you will need a provider that supports nodejs, simple PHP hosting won't be enough.

Comment: I developed the backend of a website in JavaScript (by using node.js), instead of PHP like I did before.
Can you recommend some node.js provider? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want hosting that supports Node.js then you need a hosting plan that either:

- Grants full access to the server (so you can install and manage Node.js yourself) *or*
- Explicitly supports Node.js

Comment: Okay, that is what I feared. Thank you. :)